# Phalcon Micro Application(facing prob with finish middleware event)

Tags: php, web-services, phalcon, middleware

I am facing a problem while implementing micro application in which i want a middle ware that is executed after response is send to browser. As mentioned in documentation of phalcon *finish middle ware* suppose to that work but its not working, browser still waiting to complete whole process then it return response.

my code is like:

```
$app->before(function() use ($app, $di) { $di->get('log')->log("This is a message before"); $di->get('log')->close(); });

$testCtrl = new testCtrl();
$app->get('/ctrltest', array($testCtrl, "indexAction"));

$app->after(function() use ($app, $di) {
     echo "after";
    $di->get('log')->log("This is a message after");
    $di->get('log')->close();
});

$app->finish(function() use ($app, $di) {
        $count = 100000;
        while ($count) {`enter code here`
            $di->get('log')->log("count " . $count);
            $count--;
        }
});
```

the response is coming after the whole loop is executed. Any sample code or some suggestion will be helpful